# Moving elements is delayed when I'm using the onKeyDown event

Tags: javascript, delay, game-engine, keyboard-events, onkeydown

I am trying to make an element move when I hold down a key (left or right arrow in this case), but when I hold down a key the movement is delayed by about a second.  Am I using the wrong event or is there anything wrong with my code?

I am using the `onKeyDown` event to trigger the movement.

```html
<head>
<script>
 var objX = 100;  
 function blockMove(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 37) { //move left
   objX-=4;
   document.getElementById("object").style.left = objX + "px"; 
  } else if (e.keyCode ==  39) { //move right
   objX+=4;
   document.getElementById("object").style.left = objX + "px"; 
  }
 }   
 </script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="blockMove(event)">
 <div id=object style="height:10px;width:80px;background-color:red;position:absolute;top:50px;left:100px"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of waiting for the key to "repeat" you should track keydown and keyup events and have the timer repeat the movement action when a key is down (no keyup yet).

Comment: You're creating an arkanoid, aren't you?

Comment: @monxas Actually i'm just trying to get some of the most basic game mechanisms to work.

Comment: I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1f6rp91q/) from my "archives". You can adjust the speed by changing the value of `speed` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear with me, this is kind of long and possibly buggy:
(also a spoiler if you want to do it yourself)

```
<head>
<script>
    var objX = 100;     
   var leftDown = false;
   var rightDown = false;
        function blockMove(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 37 && !leftDown) { //move left
            leftDown = true;
                objX-=4;
                document.getElementById("object").style.left = objX + "px"; 
                }else if(e.keyCode ==  39 && !rightDown) { //move right
               rightDown = true;
                    objX+=4;
                    document.getElementById("object").style.left = objX + "px"; 
        }}
      function stopMove(e)
      {
         if( e.keyCode == 37 )
            leftDown = false;
         if( e.keyCode == 39 )
            rightDown = false;
      }
       function timer()
      {
         if( leftDown )
            objX -= 4;
         if( rightDown )
            objX += 4;
         document.getElementById("object").style.left = objX + "px";    
      }
      setInterval(timer, 100);
    </script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="blockMove(event)" onkeyup="stopMove(event)">
    <div id=object 
style="height:10px;width:80px;background-color:red;position:absolute;top:360px;left:100px"
    ></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than relying on the users keyboard repeat rate, which is what's ultimately causing the multiple calls to `blockMove`, you should instead use a timer to check if the object should be moving at a consistent rate (every 20ms in my below example). This means it will be a consistent experience for all users, no matter their repeat rate setting.

You then need to keep track of whether the object should be moving.  By using the `keydown` and `keyup` events, we can keep track of whether left and right are currently pressed, then just check those values within your existing `blockMove` function:

```js
//object to keep current state of keys
var keys = {
  left: false,
  right: false
};

function keydown(e) {
  //remember "down" state
  if (e.keyCode == 37)
    keys.left = true;
  if (e.keyCode == 39)
    keys.right = true;
}
function keyup(e) {
  //forget "down" state
  if (e.keyCode == 37)
    keys.left = false;
  if (e.keyCode == 39)
    keys.right = false;
}

var objX = 100;  
function blockMove(){
    //now check the key state, rather than the event object
    if (keys.left) { //move left
        objX -= 4;
    }
    if (keys.right) { //move right
        objX += 4;
    }
    document.getElementById("object").style.left = objX + "px"; 
}

//Call the movement function every 20ms
window.setInterval(blockMove, 20);
```

```html
<body onkeydown="keydown(event)" onkeyup="keyup(event)">
 <div id=object style="height:10px;width:80px;background-color:red;position:absolute;top:50px;left:100px"></div>
</body>
```

---

As discussed in the comments below, `setInterval` only guarantees a minimum time before a function will be called, and can be subject to throttling.  Along with moving DOM objects around, it's fine for learning the basics like this, but at some point you may want to look at [drawing directly onto `<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) elements and using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for handling the callbacks, as it's designed for animation, unlike `setTimeout`/`setInterval`.

Comment: good one, if you change the speed to 10 and the pixels from 4 to 2 it is even better and not hurting the eyes so much

Comment: @vtz Or pixels to 1 and speed to 5

Comment: Yeah - it's a balancing act between how frequent you want to be moving things around the screen (and therefore consuming CPU) and how smooth you want stuff to be.

Comment: @HamMan4Ever well yes but actually this will need more resource. Also we are pretty much out of hand already because seInterval is browser feature and low timings are not accurate at all  :)

Comment: Yes - moving DOM objects around and using timers is ok for learning the basics, but at some point you may want to look at the `<canvas>` element and `requestAnimationFrame`